# Wordpress: process Paypal payment and go back to page

Tags: php, paypal

I have a booking system visualized in week calendar.
When a user want to book an event (book_id) and he doesn't have credit i show a button that redirect to Paypal to process, by a plugin, the payment and then, when the payment is successful, i want to continue my flow and make the event booked for the event the users choosen.
When i try to catch IPN, with a PHP in the same page where book calendar is siutated, i cannot understand how to retrieve the "book_id" of the event to make it booked!
Hope someone can help me,
Thank you,

Angelo.

Comment: IPNs are caught by IPN listeners, which are a separate asynchronous process that has nothing to do with the page being viewed in the browser, so you will have to be more clear in what you are asking

Comment: Ok, you're right, bu IPN apart, i would like to get the book_id of the event that was set prior to switching to the paypal page in order to make an update to the db and mark the event that user chosen booked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give any details about how you're processing a PayPal payment, the best HTML/JS integration with no API is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

If you want to more robustly implement API calls from your server, then you can use the server version of the above paired with two new routes on your server, one for 'Create Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ .  The Capture Transaction route can, on success within the server, immediately mark the correct booking as paid.